# http response in Node-red

Tags: http, google-maps-api-3, ibm-cloud, node-red

In Node-red ,after performing http request(Google Maps Distance Matrix API),http response will display the HTML source directly.What happended to the process?Please help me.Thanks a lot.

[image]

If function "setShopInformation" connect with http quest "callGoogleMapsAPI" then both the http response "showDo" will display HTML source.

[image]

The showDo page after connect with "callGoogleMapsAPI"

Comment: Please try and explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to do. If you can include a screen grab of your flow it may help people work out what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the headers are getting set in the call to the googlemaps *http request* node and need to be reset before the showDo *http out* node.

Try adding this to the setDistance function

```
...
delete msg.headers;
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It help me a lot!